# Facebook chat on android with XMPP

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

What is the way to correctly establish a connection to facebook chat in android using XMPP?
I tried searching for working sample code but couldn't find one anywhere...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should first start with an XMPP library that will work on Android.  [aSmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) (based on the popular Java [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) library seems to be the best choice.  You should be able to follow a tutorial for the library you choose, and just enter in the settings for Facebook's servers.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'm familiar with the smack and asmack libraries, I couldn't find a working example on how to connect to facebook with them...